# Curve AMM - How is fee calculated when adding liquidity?

Tags: amm, curve

When adding liquidity to Curve AMM, fees are calculated by the following code

`_fee: uint256 = self.fee * N_COINS / (4 * (N_COINS - 1))`

https://github.com/curvefi/curve-contract/blob/b0bbf77f8f93c9c5f4e415bce9cd71f0cdee960e/contracts/pools/3pool/StableSwap3Pool.vy#L274

I am guessing that division by `4` means 25% of `self.fee`. But why is `self.fee` multiplied by `N_COINS / (N_COINS - 1)`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting answer from Twitter

Simple derivation for the multiplier. We want 2 things:

- Zero fee when all assets are added/removed in proportion to their balances (maintain same price)
- Adding/removing liquidity in imbalance should be equivalent to adding/removing liquidity **in balance** and then swapping

[image]

https://twitter.com/0xa9a/status/1511392050805350402
https://demo.hedgedoc.org/_Lk3HV8WSzqVGEGSep6W9g?both

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I am not affiliated with Curve, so this answer is conjectural

As the number of coins in the pool increase, the larger will be the transaction cost because of the loop of L286. So I think the factor `N_COINS / (4 * (N_COINS - 1))` is used to compensate for the extra gas cost in the fee.

[image: Adjusted fee per number of coins]